# How I feel about this place

Tags: cipher

Please don't ask me to tell you how I feel about this place. It will be better if you can figure it out on your own:

685131824113115231024135232524252281191523523724715135816222353

Formatting hint:

> 6,8,5,13,18,24,1,13,11,5,23,10,24 13,5,23 25,24 25,22,8,11 9,15,23 5,23,7 24,7,15,13,5,8,16,22,23,5,3

Cipher hint:

> Sometimes when your 1st and 2nd string starters are not doing their job, multiple _____________ are required

Comment: I will return periodically with hints as needed

Comment: Why the downvotes? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Are the missing commas deliberate?

Comment: @LeppyR64 yes that was intended to increase the difficulty since my last puzzle was answered pretty fast. My formatting hint adds spaces and commas

Comment: You could have left the spaces out, and this puzzle would have been just fine.  The line of numbers on it's own was the reason for the downvotes.  It's impossible to "solve" without just guessing.

Comment: The second hint was definitely not required.

Comment: Don't rush yourself.  Let the problem percolate.  Not everyone uses the site every minute of the day.  I seriously don't think there's need for hints before 24 hours have passed.  When you made the comment answering that the spaces were intentional I solved the problem shortly thereafter.  When I posted my comment saying you could have left the spaces out, it was already solved, just formatting at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> STACKEXCHANGE CAN BE BOTH FUN AND EDUCATIONAL
>  [image]